# MPAndroidChart. How to play scaleX animation to show the range of entities in BarChart?

Tags: java, android, animation, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndroidChart. I need to do something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKgry.gif

I faced with the problem with showing the range of entities **with animation**.
I have a BarChart, xAxis - month, yAxis - money. I need to show the selected range of entities with animation (scale to the selected range).

Methods like `setVisibleXRange(min, max)` or `setScaleMinima(scaleX, 1f);` do what I want, but without animation.
I tried to zoom to selected range using method `zoomAndCenterAnimated()`:

```
private void showMonthRange(int monthCount) {
    //find center bar entry
    BarEntry centerBarEntry = null;
    ViewPortHandler handler = barChart.getViewPortHandler();
    MPPointD topLeft = barChart.getValuesByTouchPoint(handler.contentLeft(), handler.contentTop(), YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    MPPointD bottomRight = barChart.getValuesByTouchPoint(handler.contentRight(), handler.contentBottom(), YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    int index = (int) (topLeft.x + bottomRight.x) / 2;
    for (IBarDataSet set : barChart.getBarData().getDataSets()) {
        BarEntry entry = set.getEntryForIndex(index);
        if (entry != null) {
            centerBarEntry = entry;
            break;
        }
    }

    //perform scaling by X to show the range on entities for selected monthCount (for example 3, 6, 12..etc months)
    if (centerBarEntry != null) {
        float scaleX = (float) maxMonthCount / monthCount;
        barChart.zoomAndCenterAnimated(scaleX, 1f, entry.getX(), entry.getY(), YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT, 500);
    }
}
```

But I had an exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'float com.github.mikephil.charting.components.AxisBase.mAxisRange' on a null object reference
at com.github.mikephil.charting.jobs.AnimatedZoomJob.onAnimationUpdate(AnimatedZoomJob.java:75)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animateValue(ValueAnimator.java:1522)
at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:987)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentFraction(ValueAnimator.java:654)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1048)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1065)
at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:852)
at com.github.mikephil.charting.jobs.AnimatedViewPortJob.run(AnimatedViewPortJob.java:38)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

If I use method `barChart.zoom(scaleX, 1f, entry.getX(), entry.getY(), YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);` instead of `barChart.zoomAndCenterAnimated(scaleX, 1f, entry.getX(), entry.getY(), YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT, 500);` all works perfect.
What is wring in my implementation? Why I got such exception? 
I tried to find the answer in existing questions, but didn't find any solution.

Comment: did you tried using  barchartObj.animateY(2000);

Comment: It's not I'm looking for.
I need scaleX animation to show the selected range of entities without data changing. It should looks like https://i.imgur.com/C04bHFZ.gif

Comment: You should be able to set a debugging point and check why `mAxisRange` is `null` at that point. Maybe it hasn't been prepared at that stage?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by changing the visible X range:

```
    private void animateToRange(final int newRange) {
    final float visibleRange = barChart.getVisibleXRange();
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.1f, 1f);
    animator.setDuration(300);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float ratio = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            float range;
            if (visibleRange > newRange) {
                range = visibleRange - (visibleRange - newRange) * ratio;
            } else {
                range = visibleRange + (newRange - visibleRange) * ratio;
            }

            barChart.setVisibleXRange(range, deltaRange);
            barChart.invalidate();
        }
    });
    animator.start();
}
```

This solution is suitable if you don't need manual scaling.